# PHP mail function is not working in windows

Tags: php

My **PHP** code for `sending mail` is:

```
$email_to="deepuskmr@gmail.com";
$email_subject="It works";
$email_message="Hello. I can send mail!";
$headers = "From:Dpu\r\n".
"Reply-To: sdeepu.kmr@gmail.com\r\n'" .
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
echo "mail sent!"
```

But this code not sending email. It gives the error.
[image]

My **php.ini** file settings are

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = sdeepu.kmr@gmail.com
```

I am working in `localhost`. And I am using `windows 64` machine.

Comment: You can not send mail from your local machine by using simple mail function. You need to configure SMTP setting in your mail code with header.

Comment: Please set your mail server address in place of local host.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure XAMPP to send mail from localhost?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost)

Comment: @CodeLღver,  Pravat Kumar Sahoo, suppose if I am working in server machine, what changes should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `localhost` as mail server, if you did not installed one (SMTP server), this will obviously returns you cannot connect.

You should have something like :

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 587
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the free and awesome hMail on my dev box so that I can test my email functions and not just get mail() errors!

http://www.stylus.co.za/setting-up-hmail-on-your-development-box/

Answer (score 0):

I have hosted  site on Fasthost, it is a windows server.we can’t send emails by using any arbitrary address as ‘From’ address in Fasthosts platform due to security reasons, The “from” address must be a mailbox that exists on the Fasthosts platform.